# Bijective function $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ with $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$ is monotonic increasing.

Tags: calculus, functions, examples-counterexamples

If I have a bijective real function $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ with $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b,$ I want to show it is monotonic increasing or find a counterexample.

Notice that I'm not assuming continuity, for the intermediate value theorem and the condition on endpoints would easily take care of the problem in this case, and that is why I'm stuck.  I can't think o a counterexample nor prove it. By removing the restrictions on the range (i.e. making it $\mathbb R$, forgetting about the endpoints condition and only asking injectivity) I can find a counterexample to the affirmation, so I think I must use $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$ in some way...

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$ except $f\left(a+\dfrac b3\right)=a+\dfrac {2b}3$ and $f\left(a+\dfrac {2b}3\right)=a+\dfrac b3$?

Comment: Yes this and the other answers solves it, thank you. This exact argument as actually used in a thesis I am reading, which is why I brought it here. Luckily it is fixable by first showing continuity of $f$ and then monotonicity.

Comment: You definitely need continuity for your statement to be true!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ by $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, and $f(x)=1-x$ otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If you want  nowhere monotonic function, so take $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x$ for rational $x$ and $f(x)=1-x$ for irrational $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a counterexample (assuming $a<b$):

$f(x)=x$ except $f\left(a+\dfrac {b-a}3\right)=a+\dfrac {2(b-a)}3$ and $f\left(a+\dfrac {2(b-a)}3\right)=a+\dfrac {b-a}3;$

$f$ is a bijective real function with $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$,

but $f$ is not monotonic increasing because $a+\dfrac {b-a}3<a+\dfrac {2(b-a)}3$

but $f\left(a+\dfrac {b-a}3\right)>f\left(a+\dfrac {2(b-a)}3\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, @JyrkiLahtonen; you are correct; I have edited accordingly